# Possible to have "inheritance" in html?

Tags: html, inheritance

Let's say all of my html pages will have a top bar and banner with the same content. 
Rather than copy the code for these content on all html pages, is it possible to have pages inherit the content from a base html page?

For example : base.html can have the top bar, banner, etc (all repeated content)
Remaining pages (index.html, about.html, etc) can inherit the content from base.html and then add more content.

Is this possible in html or do I have to copy and paste repeating content all the time?

Comment: This is exactly how server-side includes work.

If you save a text file with a single line: `<?php phpinfo() ?>` to your root (save it as `info.php` or similar), and then view the page in your browser, you will be able to see if your server has PHP installed (and what version etc.)

Comment: Also see Server Side Includes: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/ssi.html

Answer (score 5):

In this situations (as far as I know)

1. You can use template based editors like Dreamweaver
2. You can use framesets (don't use them)
3. You can use iframe (meh.)
4. You can convert your files to PHP and just use a single include command (Y)
5. Copy and paste whole thing and when you get 100 pages, try to add a new menu...

I'd like to see other solutions too.

Example:

Lets say I've created a **template.html** it's something like

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>asd</title>
    style tags keywords bla bla bla 
   </head>
<body>
   <div class="menu">
      yeah I've my menu here well designed
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      unique content here
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Allright this is my one html file. Lets take top section of the page. Menu will be same but content will be changed so this is top of the page:

```
<html>
   <head>
    <title>asd</title>
    style tags keywords bla bla bla 
   </head>
<body>
   <div class="menu">
      yeah I've my menu here well designed
   </div>
```

Save this part as **top.php** Now let's see what have we left:

```
<div class="content">
          unique content here
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This will be our post page. But how can we get codes from top.php? Just like that:

```
<?php include("top.php"); ?>
<div class="content">
          unique content here
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Now, save this as **page1.php** BINGO! You did not wrote anthing about menu but include method will bring it for you.

Include basically writes everything from a file to another. You can check differences for include_once, require, require_once too.

Allright, we've created our first page. What about second one? Exactly the same:

```
<?php include("top.php"); ?>
<div class="content">
          my second page here
       </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Save this as **page2.php**

Well, you need to change your menu now but there are two pages, two hundred pages, two million pages... Who cares. Just change **top.php** that's all.

Please note that in this codes; top.php, page1.php and page2.php are in SAME directory. If you want to include from another path, you must use for example:

```
<?php include("../top.php"); ?>
//OR
<?php include("myFiles/theme/top.php); ?>
```

depending on your path.

I hope this helps. Read PHP guides for include. It's really easy.

You need a testing server (or you can use a local server like WAMP, XAMP etc.) to execute PHP files.

Comment: Basically correct. There are other server side languages out there, not just PHP (though it is probably the easiest to learn and best suited for this simple use case). And definitely a no to the (i)frames!

Comment: Can you give an example or describe the PHP method?

Comment: Also: static site generators (like [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws) or [jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com)).

Answer (score -1):

You can create template page and include it to the all new pages as javascript

`<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/template.js">  </script>`

Same way with php - using include