# Inheritance in HTML

Tags: html

Let's say I have two or more HTML pages that have the same header and footer. In this case, is it possible to have a single file that contains the header and footer such that I can inherit from it in the other pages? Or are there any other ways so that I don't have to repeat the header and footer for every single file?

I have read and understood a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610837/possible-to-have-inheritance-in-html) that had already been asked and answered at StackOverflow.

What I am asking is that can I achieve it using other technologies apart from PHP?

Comment: Probably every web server framework on the planet supports this.

Comment: and every template engine.

Comment: You could also combine the different pieces by javascript in the browser

Comment: For simple html files, I believe you can use iframes https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Comment: @BryanOakley - I am extremely sorry but as I am new to this I do not know all those technologies. So, can you please give me some reference point or framework name or examples with which I can start with?

Comment: @vikingosegundo - I am extremely sorry but as I am new to this I do not know all those technologies. So, can you please give me some reference point or framework name or examples with which I can start with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible to have "inheritance" in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610837/possible-to-have-inheritance-in-html)

Comment: sure: https://www.google.com/search?q=web+framework&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Why am I getting the downvotes? I genuinely asked a question as I really do not know the answer? If someone already knows an answer then why will he/she come to StackOverflow? Why does this site even exist then?

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Thanks! I didn't even know what is a web framwork before coming here.

Comment: and this is one reason why you receive down vote: your question is showing no effort. another: by definition research question are off topic here.

Comment: btw: the current two answers would also qualify for down votes, as they aren't complete and depend on links that might go away in the future.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - I think you are confused. I wanted to know how to have same footer or header in all HTML pages? So, I [googled](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=same+header+footer+all+html+pages&oq=same+header+footer+all+html+pages). The first three StackOverflow answers doesn't mention anything on web framework. So, how do I show effort on something that I don't know?

Comment: do you call clicking through 3 SO questions showing some effort? if you would have entered any combination of *web*, *html*, *development* into google, it should have just been few clicks till you learned about *web framework*.

Comment: @vikingosegundo - Look at the other results too. All of them talks about php. That's why I already mentioned in my question that I have read about php.

Comment: you only found crappy results as you did not invest enough effort into research — as I explained before. but even if: your question is not the right format for SO. It has no definitive best answer. please check the help section for explanations what are good question for SO, and what aren't.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking other than PHP, there are many templating engines available.

- Such as static site generators like: [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/)
- You can also use [Javascript
  Templating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_templates)

I prefer **ejs**, which works great with gulp. [ejs with
   gulp](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application)

Comment: Please think about accepting or upvoting if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without excluding PHP, templating engines, such as [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html), are made to do just this.